# How to format Duration

Tags: date, go, iso8601

How can I format/stringify  a time.Duration into [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) ? e.g. `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S`

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [golang time.Since() with months and years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530251/golang-time-since-with-months-and-years)

Comment: @icza Great answer there--revised this to link to your answer, and linked to a library linked in another answer there. I think the questions asked are just different enough to keep both (ISO period format vs. human-readable "X time ago") but all good if folks want to mark dupe. Obviously the algorithm at the core of the answer (calculating calendar periods) is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just have a `time.Duration` and no context, you're out of luck: `Duration` just counts nanoseconds, and the number of nanoseconds in a month varies with the number of days. There are similar, smaller irregularities with daylight savings transitions ([mentioned in docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)), leap days, and leap seconds (Go's `time` package doesn't even consider leap seconds).

Given two `time.Time` values, it looks like [`github.com/rickb777/date/period`](https://godoc.org/github.com/rickb777/date/period) will do what you want, including formatting--this prints `P3Y1M21DT17H18M58S`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/rickb777/date/period"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2012-11-03T13:41:02Z")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    t2, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2015-12-25T07:00:00Z")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(period.Between(t1, t2))
}
```

I found the link to that, along with other info, in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36530251/) user icza linked to about the closely-related problem of printing a human-readable "X months ago" string.

Underneath, you're calling `Year()`, `Month()`, etc. on both `Time`s, and getting their differences (accounting for varying lengths of months). [icza wrote out code for that answering that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531443/2714852). Then formatting and storing those differences is the relatively easier part, and is also done by, e.g. [ChannelMeter/iso8601duration](https://godoc.org/github.com/ChannelMeter/iso8601duration)'s `Duration` (adapted from [BrianHicks/finch](https://github.com/BrianHicks/finch)).

I don't know what nits there might still be for total standard compliance, but that gets you pretty close.

Comment: github.com/rickb777/date/period is a gem