# Difference between two time.Time objects

Tags: datetime, go, time

Very new to the 'Go'. Question might be basic one.

I have two time.Time objects and I want to get the difference between the two in terms of hours/minutes/seconds. Lets say:

```
t1 = 2016-09-09 19:09:16 +0530 IST
t2 = 2016-09-09 19:09:16 +0530 IST
```

In above case, since the difference is 0. It should give me 00:00:00. Consider another case:

```
t1 = 2016-09-14 14:12:48 +0530 IST
t2 = 2016-09-14 14:18:29 +0530 IST
```

In this case, difference would be 00:05:41. I looked at the https://godoc.org/time but could not make anything out of it.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You may use [`Time.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub) to get the difference between the 2 [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) values, result will be a value of [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration).

When printed, a `time.Duration` formats itself "intelligently":

```
t1 := time.Now()
t2 := t1.Add(time.Second * 341)

fmt.Println(t1)
fmt.Println(t2)

diff := t2.Sub(t1)
fmt.Println(diff)
```

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10 23:05:41 +0000 UTC
5m41s
```

If you want the time format `HH:mm:ss`, you may constuct a `time.Time` value and use its [`Time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) method like this:

```
out := time.Time{}.Add(diff)
fmt.Println(out.Format("15:04:05"))
```

Output:

```
00:05:41
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7Uyk__vH2j).

Of course this will only work if the time difference is less than a day. If the difference may be bigger, then it's another story. The result must include days, months and years. Complexity increases significnatly. See this question for details:

[golang time.Since() with months and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530251/golang-time-since-with-months-and-years/36531443#36531443)

The solution presented there solves this issue by showing a function with signature:

```
func diff(a, b time.Time) (year, month, day, hour, min, sec int)
```

You may use that even if your times are within 24 hours (in which case `year`, `month` and `day` will be `0`).

Comment: Bang on! Thank you.

Comment: How about if I say I need only hours or minutes?

Comment: @HemantBhargava Then use a different layout string, one that only contains hours and minutes: `out.Format("15:04")`

Comment: This is not working.

`t1 := time.Now()
`t2 := t1.Add(time.Second * 34100)

`diff := t2.Sub(t1)
`fmt.Println(diff.Minutes())

out := time.Time{}.Add(diff)
fmt.Println(out.Format("15:30"))


This outputs :
568.3333333333334
09:90

Which is not correct.

Comment: @HemantBhargava Yes of course because `"15:30"` is an invalid layout string. Please take the time and read the doc at [`Time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) to know what the layout string is. Using `out.Format("15:04:05")` outputs `09:28:20` which is correct. If you only need hour+min, then use `out.Format("15:04")` which outputs `09:28`, as you can see this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mEEpMNNt6P).

Comment: Different formats are listed here: https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Answer (score 41):

Actually, the `time` package's documentation does discuss it:

https://godoc.org/time#Time.Sub

https://godoc.org/time#Duration.Hours

You should produce a `Duration` object using `Sub()` and then use one of the `Seconds()`, `Minutes()`, `Hours()`.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        t1 := time.Date(1984, time.November, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
        t2 := time.Date(1984, time.November, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
        fmt.Printf("The hours difference is: %f", t1.Sub(t2).Hours())
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the quick answer. I did it:

`var duration time.Duration = trip.EndTime.Sub(trip.StartTime)
`fmt.Println("Time difference: Minutes", duration.Minutes(), "Seconds: ", duration.Seconds())

But this does not seem to be giving the right numbers.

Comment: What is `trip.EndTime\StartTime` ?

Comment: Sorry! Think of it as:

t1 = trip.StartTime
t2 = trip.EndTime

Comment: It is OK, but how does it implemented ?

Comment: Implemented what? I did not write anything else than above two lines for the duration.

Comment: As I said, think of trip.Starttime and trip.EndTime as t1 and t2 respectively.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the edit. In your code, in case I need to get only hours/minutes, then?

Comment: Then just use `fmt.Printf("The hours difference is: %d", t1.Sub(t2).Hours())` or `fmt.Printf("The minutes difference is: %d", t1.Sub(t2).Minutes())`

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 common ways:

straight forward one:

```
startTime := time.Now()
diff := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
```

shorter one (a bit):

```
startTime := time.Now()
diff := time.Since(startTime)
```

Comment: Does since use UTC?

Answer (score 4):

To complement Shmulik Klein's answer:

Another way to calculate disjoint hours/minutes/seconds out of a time.Duration:

https://play.golang.org/p/VRoXG5NxLo

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1 := time.Date(1984, time.November, 3, 13, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    t2 := time.Date(1984, time.November, 3, 10, 23, 34, 0, time.UTC)

    hs := t1.Sub(t2).Hours()

    hs, mf := math.Modf(hs)
    ms := mf * 60

    ms, sf := math.Modf(ms)
    ss := sf * 60

    fmt.Println(hs, "hours", ms, "minutes", ss, "seconds")
}
```

> 2 hours 36 minutes 25.999999999999375 seconds

note:

- slight precision loss due to the use of the float64 type
- we ignore leap seconds and assume every minute has 60 seconds

Comment: leap seconds considerations and data type consideration?  this is a $1000 answer to $10 question...

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://play.golang.org/p/oRqOyaUYN0W)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func TimeAsString(dt float64) string {
    time := dt
    hours := math.Floor(time / 3600)
    minutes := math.Ceil(math.Mod(time, 3600)/60) - 1
    seconds := int(time) % 60
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v:%v", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

func main() {
    mytime := 0.0
    last := time.Now()

    tick := time.Tick(33 * time.Millisecond)
    for {

        select {
        case <-tick:
            dt := time.Since(last).Seconds()
            last = time.Now()

            mytime += dt
            fmt.Println(TimeAsString(mytime))
        }

    }
}
```