# How to calculate end date

Tags: date, go, time

I'm trying to calculate endDate given the startDate and duration.

Example:

```
func calculateEndDate(startDate *time.Time, duration uint32, durationType uint32) *time.Time {
    endDate := &time.Time{}
    switch enum.DurationType(durationType) {
    case enum.DayType:
        temp := startDate.Add(time.Duration(24*duration) * time.Hour)
        endDate = &temp
    }
    return endDate
}
```

Is this the idiomatic way of doing it? And should I follow this pattern if I want to use different types of time like `years` or `months`?

Comment: time.Time.AddDate is what you are looking for. Rule of thumb: Read all documentation first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest would be to just use [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) and the [`time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method to calculate the end date:

```
t := time.Now()
d := 3*time.Hour + 20*time.Minute

end := t.Add(d)
```

If date can be greater than a day, then this isn't sufficient anymore, because daylight savings and leap years should be taken into account. Also `time.Duration` cannot represent a duration greater than 290 years (approximately).

In that case duration should be given as a `(years, months, days)` ternary, and [`time.AddDate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate) should be used.

```
t := time.Now()
years, months, days := 15, 2, 3

end := t.AddDate(years, months, days)
```

See related questions:

[time.Since() with months and years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530251/time-since-with-months-and-years/36531443#36531443)

[Difference between two time.Time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260599/difference-between-two-time-time-objects/40260853#40260853)

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic way would be:

```golang
duration := time.Duration(/* some amount of time */)
endDate := startDate.Add(duration)
```

In this example `duration` can be any amount of time, up to [approximately 290 years](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration):

```golang
duration := 10 * time.Second   // 10 seconds
duration := 15 * time.Minute   // 15 minutes
duration := 5 * time.Hour      // 5 hours
duration := 6 * 24 * time.Hour // 6 24-hour days
```

etc