# golang conditionals on the time difference (sub)

Tags: go

I have two times, `t1` and `t2`.
To calculate the difference, I use,

```
diff := t2.sub(t1)
```

The above code returns the difference like `10m30s`, `1h3m59s` etc.

I need to create some conditions for the difference.
For example,

```
if diff <= 5m {
   do this
}
if diff > 20m {
   do that
}
```

My question is if there is any built-in way to compare the time difference.

My other option would be to parse returned diff with regex and then compare. But I was looking for some efficient ways like the `sub` which the time package offers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two time.Time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260599/difference-between-two-time-time-objects)

Comment: @rustyhu I am not looking for the difference between time objects. What I am looking for is something to perse the object (which itself is the difference between two time objects)

Comment: Why not `if diff <= (5*time.Second) {...`? The value `10m30s` is just the output of the `String() string` method implemented on the type `time.Duration` which is the type of `diff` and which is an `int64` underneath.

Answer (score 3):

`t2.Sub(t1)` returns a duration, and you can simply use the comparison operators, for example:

```
d, _ := time.ParseDuration("4m4s")
if d <= 5 * time.Second {
    fmt.Println("<= than limit")
} else {
    fmt.Println("> than limit")
}
```

Comment: this only works if I have the duration in string. It doesn't work with the output of sub function this way because I the output of `diff:=t2.Sub(t1)` i.e `diff` is in different type.

Comment: You got something wrong there. `t2.Sub(t1)` returns `time.Duration`.

Comment: Yes, it does. This is why `ParseDuration` is unnecessary. I can just use the `diff.Minutes()` directly. `ParseDuration` is only necessary if the duration is in `string`. (If I understood the thing correctly)

Comment: I think you still got it wrong. The above code is just an example, how to get to the duration. It doesn't matter how you got a duration, you can always use the comparison operators on it. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/1Iz7tIytCqR

Comment: So both `ParseDuration` and `time.Sub()` returns `time.Duration`?

Comment: Of course, which can be seen in the docs (https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration and https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Sub). Any Go IDE will probably show that too and you can print the type too to try it out.

Comment: I see it does. https://play.golang.org/p/Plyt7N2247c

Answer (score 2):

### **Way 1:** When we use `sub` to get the duration

A very simple alternative is to directly use the output of the `sub` function. The `func sub` returns `time.Duration` type. So just adding `.Minutes()` method with it would serve the purpose in my case.

```
    t1 := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(60011 * time.Millisecond)
    t2 := time.Now()
    timeDiff := t2.Sub(t1)
    fmt.Println(timeDiff)
    fmt.Printf("\nIn just minites: %.f\n", timeDiff.Minutes())
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sht_Q4P3Ssh)

### **Way 2:** When we have the duration in `string`

If we would have the "difference" as a `string` (`"10m2s"`) type then I believe we need to use the `ParseDuration` function. From the godocs [ParseDuration](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration)
From the doc,

> ParseDuration parses a duration string. A duration string is a possibly signed sequence of decimal numbers, each with optional fraction and a unit suffix, such as "300ms", "-1.5h" or "2h45m". Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s", "m", "h".

I am thinking of using it like the following,

```
t = "10h10m6s"
timeDiff, _ := time.ParseDuration(t)
numberOfHours := timeDiff.Hours()
numberOfMinutes := timeDiff.Minutes()
numberOfSeconds := timeDiff.Seconds()
numberofNanosec := timeDiff.Nanoseconds()
```

Find the example snippet on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ONLOaZotHjt)

<strike>So in any of the above cases, we can use `time.Minutes()` to compare the duration.</strike>. As [@gopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13631587/gopher) pointed out that to compare with any time range we do not need to convert it to any period of time (e,g `Mintues()`, `Seconds()`) but we can just compare with a required time period. As [@Haris Osmanagić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059744/haris-osmanagi%C4%87) pointed out that this works for both of the output of `ParseDuration` and `time.Sub()` as they both returns `time.Duration` type. So we can do something like the following,

```
if timeDiff < 5 * time.Minutes() {
   do something
} else if timeDiff > 5 * time.Minutes(){
   do something else
} else {
   do nothing
}
```

An example is on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1VGo0zyK2ip).

Comment: A duration is an int64 count of nanoseconds.  The Minutes() method converts the count of nanoseconds to a floating point number of minutes.  It's more direct skip the conversion to float and compare nanoseconds:  `if timeDiff < 5 * time.Minute { do something }`.  Note that `time.Minute` is the number of nanoseconds in a minute and the constant expression `5 * time.Minute` is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Not only that, the above approach with comparing minutes will work only as long as you know you'll have to compare minutes. As soon as the threshold is something other than X minutes (e.g. 3 minutes, 10 seconds, 250 ms), the check becomes much more complex.

Comment: @gopher make sense. In that case, converting the `timeDiff` to minutes is pointless. :/  Thanks