# time since in days, hours, minutes, seconds format

Tags: go, time

Is there a way to format the output of [time.Since()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Since) to add days when aplicable, something like:

```
[days]d[hours]h[minutes]m[seconds]s
```

The current format seems to use only hours as the maximum unit:

```
start := time.Unix(1411691219, 0)
diff := time.Since(start)

21132h9m41.714117301s
```

But I would like to use days instead of hours, in order to obtain something like:

```
880d12h9m41.7s
```

I am currently using the following `TimeDiff` function to produce the desired output, but wondering if there is an easy/better/native way of achieving this.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Unix(1411691219, 0)
    diff := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("diff = %s\n", diff)
    fmt.Printf("diff = %s\n", TimeDiff(start))
}

func TimeDiff(t time.Time) string {
    diff := time.Since(t)
    days := diff / (24 * time.Hour)
    hours := diff % (24 * time.Hour)
    minutes := hours % time.Hour
    seconds := math.Mod(minutes.Seconds(), 60)
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    if days > 0 {
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%dd", days))
    }
    if hours/time.Hour > 0 {
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%dh", hours/time.Hour))
    }
    if minutes/time.Minute > 0 {
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%dm", minutes/time.Minute))
    }
    if seconds > 0 {
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%.1fs", seconds))
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

Comment: This is a _hard_ problem as days have different durations: Not just leap seconds, but daylight saving. If your day is 24h: Fine. Problem becomes more obvious if you think about displaying time deltas in month or year units.

Comment: Currently I mainly want to know how much a process took, not doing any date calculations regarding the dates.

Comment: Related: [golang time.Since() with months and years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530251/golang-time-since-with-months-and-years/36531443#36531443).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your exact question:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func FormatSince(t time.Time) string {
    const (
        Decisecond = 100 * time.Millisecond
        Day        = 24 * time.Hour
    )
    ts := time.Since(t)
    sign := time.Duration(1)
    if ts < 0 {
        sign = -1
        ts = -ts
    }
    ts += +Decisecond / 2
    d := sign * (ts / Day)
    ts = ts % Day
    h := ts / time.Hour
    ts = ts % time.Hour
    m := ts / time.Minute
    ts = ts % time.Minute
    s := ts / time.Second
    ts = ts % time.Second
    f := ts / Decisecond
    return fmt.Sprintf("%dd%dh%dm%d.%ds", d, h, m, s, f)
}
```

Output:

```
diff = 21136h26m58.574146433s
diff = 880d16h26m58.6s
```

For Go 1.8 and earlier, this gives you the difference in absolute (UTC) time. It may not match the difference in wall clock time which can be affected by daylight saving time. It may also be affected by adjustments to the system wall (real-time) clock.

From Go 1.9 onward, the difference will be computed using a monotonic clock which is not affected by changes to the system wall clock time or daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

A naïve implementation might be: https://play.golang.org/p/VsVeIhoLGi

(Note the assumption on the day duration constant).