# Date delta human readable format

Tags: date, time, timedelta, delta

I looking for a way to output how old something is for some reporting. I'm pretty open to approach, libraries, packages, and languages. Though bash, golang, and python would be preferred. I have already researched many different ways to do this. Though I keep seeing the same results which is not my ideal output. The outputs I am seeing are something like 45 days ago, or 1.06 months ago.

I'm looking for a way to output hours, days, weeks, months, and years. And example of this output would be "Last ran: 1 month, 2 weeks, 4 days, and 9 hours ago". Right now I'm currently getting the dates as epoch timestamps from bash `date` tool. So I can do any kind of conversion necessary to input. For sake of example here are some inputs: `2020-03-19T05:12:14`, `2019-08-27T08:47:27`, `2020-05-12T11:10:18`, `2020-02-01T07:40:01`. I'm trying to get how old these time stamps are from current time/date. So essentially what `date` outputs. Or other language equivalent.

More examples to demonstrate what I don't want `echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(date -d "2020-08-27T05:47:27" +%s) )/(60*60*24) )) => 16` Instead I want 2 weeks and 2 days. Same for something over a month or year old. Hours is the smallest increment that I really care about.

Comment: in Python, you could use dateutil's [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) class to obtain what you describe

Comment: in Go, you might want to have a look at [icza's timex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36530251/10197418)